# Google Classroom API : Unable to receive push notifications for courseworks and student submissions (COURSE_WORK_CHANGES)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-pubsub, service-accounts, google-classroom

We are seriously blocked. We have followed the documentation below (among many others) to set up the pub/sub pipelines, create service accounts, assign permissions and use the right scopes and feed types for registrations.

https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications

So programmatically we are able to do the following in .net using the API :

1. We can Create Courses
2. We can create registrations for a given courseid
3. We create/update courseworks for the course that we have created a registration.

All good so far,

BUT, we don't receive notifications for that created/update course work.

some code for clarity :

```
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("sa-something@precise-asset-259113.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
       {
          User = "impersonated user",
          Scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students" ,
                                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
                                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.push-notifications" }}
       .FromPrivateKey("My private key"));

        //Authorize request
        var result = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });

        // We get courses
        var courses = service.Courses.List().Execute();

        // We get one course for registration
        var course = courses.Courses.First();

        // We create registration
        var registration = service.Registrations.Create(new Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.Data.Registration()
        {
            Feed = new Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.Data.Feed()
            {
                FeedType = "COURSE_WORK_CHANGES",
                CourseWorkChangesInfo = new Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.Data.CourseWorkChangesInfo()
                {
                    CourseId = course.Id
                },
            },
            CloudPubsubTopic = new Google.Apis.Classroom.v1.Data.CloudPubsubTopic()
            {
                TopicName = "projects/precise-asset-259113/topics/test"
            },

        });

        //Successful response - We get a registrationID
        var response = registration.Execute();

        var courseWork = new CourseWork()
        {
                 CourseId = course.Id,
                 Title = "Ver Test",
                 Description = "Calculus",
                 WorkType = "ASSIGNMENT",
                 MaxPoints = 20.0,
                 State = "PUBLISHED",
                 AlternateLink = "www.uni.com",
                 CreatorUserId = course.OwnerId,
                 CreationTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                 DueTime = new TimeOfDay() { Hours = 5, Minutes = 10, Nanos = 10, Seconds = 10 },
                 DueDate = new Date() { Day = 3, Month = 12, Year = 2019 },
                 Assignment = new Assignment() { StudentWorkFolder = new DriveFolder() { AlternateLink = "Somewhere", Title = "My Calculus" } }
        };

        //Create course work for the course that we registered
        var courseWorkResponse = service.Courses.CourseWork.Create(courseWork, course.Id).Execute();

       SubscriberServiceApiClient subscriber = SubscriberServiceApiClient.Create();
       SubscriptionName subscriptionName = new SubscriptionName("precise-asset-259113", "test");

         PullResponse pullResponse = subscriber.Pull(
            subscriptionName, returnImmediately: true, maxMessages: 20);

       // Check for push notifications BUT ....NADA!!!
        foreach (ReceivedMessage msg in pullResponse.ReceivedMessages)
        {
            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Message.Data.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"Message {msg.Message.MessageId}: {text}");
        }
```

Can you please assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to change in order to ensure you get the notifications:

1. You need to create your subscription before you send the request that will generate the Pub/Sub message. Only messages published *after* the successful creation of a subscription are guaranteed to be received by subscribers for that subscription.
2. A single pull request with `returnImmediately` set to true is unlikely to return any messages, even if a message has been published. With this property set, if there are no messages immediately in memory of the server reached, the empty response is returned. You should always set `returnImmediately` to false. This still won't guarantee that messages are returned in a single request/response, even if there are messages available, but it will make it more likely.
3. Ideally, you would use the [asynchronous client library](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull), which opens a stream to the Cloud Pub/Sub service and receives messages as soon as they are available. If you are going to use the synchronous `Pull` method directly, then you need to keep many of them outstanding simultaneously in order to ensure delivery of messages with minimal latency. As soon as you receive a `PullResponse` for any of the outstanding requests, you should immediately open up another request to replace it. The goal of the asynchronous client library is to prevent one from having to take all of these step manually to ensure efficient delivery.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Kindly note that we have already tried 1 and 2. We can definitely try the async version of the library but I believe that the above code version should work for our initial "proof of concept" version". We believe this is a very weird permission error. We have switched off "returnImmeditaely". Also, we know that the subscription exists long before we start creating registrations and course works. Can we contact someone from the Google Clouds platform for reviewing the way we have created the service accounts and permissions. We are really at a dead end here.

Comment: Some more information. We have created a G Suite service account and we have enabled domain user domain delegation. We are using an "impersonateduser" as shown in the code above. We have assigned permissions to googleclassroom notifications etc. We have really followed all available documentations. We've based our entire architecture on a component that is supposed to process push notifications.

Comment: For testing purposes, to verify that we have set up the pubsub pipeline and service accounts correctly, we added message manually using the Google Cloud Console. We access the Console using our g Suite service account. Those test messages are coming through. The subscription already exists and THEN we start adding course works and student submissions for the registered course. However, nothing is coming through but only the messages we created manually ourselves. Our only plan of action at the moment is going through google documentations, reviewing our set up. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling (after spending hours trying to solve the same problem), that it is because apparently (I have no idea why......) students cannot register for Google Classroom push notifications; only teachers. This begs the question though, why on earth would a teacher want to be notified when they change something about their own course, and why wouldn't students have the ability to be notified of changes in THEIR course work??? Sorry had to vent